# How to read backward from the end of file in less or more?

Tags: unix, solaris, less

I've found one way so far: `less +G filename`, but it scrolls up line-by-line only with <kbd>↑</kbd>.

What's a more powerful `less` usage which provides scrolling by page, backward pattern search, and so on?

Answer (score 282, accepted):

I'm sure someone else has a better answer, but

With "less" after you've opened the file:

```
G goes to the bottom of the file

^b goes up one page

? searches backwards.
```

As you said, you can open the file with +G and then use ? and ^b to scroll up.  There are likely clever awk things you can do to achieve the same thing in a script.

Comment: Ctrl-b works, but b (by itself) also does.

Comment: Oops! I'm so conditioned to use vi keys that I just use those in less as well. Yes -- b moves you up a page in less, but only backwards one word at a time in vi. I'm impatient; I want a page at a time, and my walnut sized brain can't remember if I'm in vi or less sometimes...

Comment: less your file, then type 'h' => you get a nice per-operation manual. Very neat, no need for external guides or the manpage IMO.

Comment: in fact, `? = shift + /`, `/` is to search forwards.

Comment: In fact `Shift + G` goes to the bottom of the file

Comment: @HongboZhu in us keyboard layout, but I don't think on others

Comment: Using `+G` on the command line works for the first file. But when viewing multiple files with `less +G` only the first file will be shown from the end, the rest of the files are still shown from the beginning.

Answer (score 101):

For variety, if you actually want/need to read a file backwards (last line first):

```
tac filename | less
```

Comment: That's mostly a linux / gnuism...

Comment: Fun fact: `tac` is `cat` backwards

Comment: This was my childhood cat's name. I don't think I realized why until now.

Comment: Anybody heard of anything like `ztac` for gzipped files (ie `zcat` but backwards)?

Comment: @irbanana: [One way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/132642/382). But it doesn't save any time on large files because the whole file has to be decompressed.

Answer (score 12):

use:

```
less +F /path/to/your/file
```

that's less but starting from the bottom. Also, with +F, if the file is being written to while you are using less, that additional content gets output. This can be useful for logs.

Use the up arrow key to go backwards line by line or ctl+b to go page by page.

Comment: This not only goes to the end of the file, it waits for additional output at the end, like `tail -f`. If this isn't what you want, you should use `+G` instead.

Comment: you're right @MichaelHampton

Comment: and you can stop waiting for additional output by pressing CTRL+C. It stops waiting for new data but does not exit less.

Answer (score 8):

`w` goes up by page. `?` does reverse search. `h` brings up online help.

Answer (score 4):

tail -r | less

I don't know why anyone didn't think of this one.  Tail grabs the end of a file really easy.  Is -r not a common option?

Comment: Using tail (GNU coreutils) 8.13 on Ubuntu 12.02 here. No such option as `-r`.

Comment: I think `tail -r` is a BSD/macOS thing - those environments don't have `tac`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised nobody brought this up before, but:

`?pattern` searches for *pattern* backwards.

`N` finds the previous match of the pattern (that is, searching backwards).

For reference, `/pattern` searches for *pattern* forward and `n` finds the next match of the pattern. That's the way the search is commonly used.

Answer (score 2):

While using `more` or `journalctl -xe` using space bar takes you 1 page down. That worked for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, after you have started less on a file:

alt + "end-key"

With "end-key" I mean the key that is usually located below the "home-key" on a keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file straight to the end (`+G`) with `less +G path/to/filename`.

It will automatically start "calculating line numbers." If the file is huge (ex: many GiB), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to stop that, since it could take forever.

Now, here are some keys to navigate:

1. <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> = scroll one line up
2. <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> = scroll one line down
3. <kbd>u</kbd> = scroll a half page up
4. <kbd>d</kbd> = scroll a half page down
5. <kbd>PageUp</kbd> = scroll a full page up
6. <kbd>PageDown</kbd> = scroll a full page down
7. Use `/` to search forwards, pressing <kbd>n</kbd> to go to the next match *down*, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> to go to the next match *up*.
8. Use `?` to search backwards, pressing <kbd>n</kbd> to go to the next match *up*, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> to go to the next match *down*.

### References

1. The question itself, which reminded me of `less +G filename` to open the file straight to the end.
2. [This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/151640/357116).
3. My own knowledge.
4. `man less`

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for something specific, this might do it:

```
cat yourfile.txt | grep "something specific" | less
```

I use it for searching log files. It's still in the 'wrong' order though, but much shorter.

After reading Dennis Williamson's answer, that's my new method =)

Comment: I don't need `cat` with `grep` -- `grep $StRING $FILENAME | less`

Comment: Imho, that's an absolutely different question.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps some people did not understood what [dr01](https://serverfault.com/a/934147/397687) meant. I try to put it in other words.

- Open the file in less
- Forward search: Enter the key /
- Backward search: Enter the key ?
- For both of the preceding: Enter your search term now
- Press enter
- Press n to search for the next finding
- Press N to search for the previous finding